# ClassNotFound exception when I run my packaged jar, it works when launching it using Idea

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jar, development-environment

The strange thing is that I don't use the missing class `DispatchApplication` and because I have no error when launching it using idea, so i do not know how to debug it.

I tried to clean idea cache, clean local maven repository, restart my PC
but my colleague can run with a jar, and each of them don't know why this happen and how solve this

```
D:\projectFolder\midel-data\data-integration\data-integration-service\target>java -jar data-integration-service-1.0.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lty.dispatch.DispatchApplication
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing 3rd party jars from your classpath

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an issue with dependencies.
You might want to check your IDE settings if you have explicitly enabled any additional jars in the class path.

Also, check out your pom.xml/.gradle file for any difference in dependency versions.

If this class is part of some custom jar, make sure you include it while packaging your jar.

Comment: thanks, it has been solved, the class can't be found is the class be imported by maven plugin, when i delete the maven plugin config, and clear maven local repository, it runs